# Why does SCHEMA_NAME() return 'dbo' after setting setting DEFAULT_SCHEMA via ALTER USER [username] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA when I open a new tab in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

I want to change my `default schema` on a database from `'dbo'` to `'schemaname'`

I am not a member of `sysadmin`.

I do know that I "should always use fully qualified table names", but I would like to use the `DEFAULT_SCHEMA` capability of SQL Server, because it makes writing adhoc queries simpler.

If I do this:

```
USE [databasename]
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()  -- returns 'dbo'  
ALTER USER [username] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[schemaname] EXECUTE AS USER='username'  
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()  -- returns 'schemaname'
```

...it works as expected.

However, if I then open a new tab in SSMS, this happens:

```
select SCHEMA_NAME()  -- returns 'dbo'
select USER           -- returns 'dbo'
```

I have tried restarting SSMS.
If I look at my user properties under "Security" in the database, it does show that the Default Schema is set to `schemaname`, but I still get dbo when I query `SCHEMA_NAME()` or `USER`.

Does anyone know how one might get this to work as desired?  I know it is possible, because I have achieved it many times in the past, but I've been away from MSSQL for a while and seem to have forgotten the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you have posted, you're impersonating `username` with the `execute as 'username'` statement. You should be able to see that by doing the same `select USER` in the same window as you're running the `ALTER USER` statement.

In your second set of statements, it shows that you're running as dbo. You haven't changed the default schema for that user and so it's correctly returning dbo as the default schema for that user.

Comment: Ah, I guess i didn't write the question well enough....I tried without the execute as initially but that didn't work either.  It is utterly bizarre to me that it seems next to impossible to find out how to do this on the internet, even though I've been able to successfully do it so many times in the past.  And of course, SO being what it is, both my question and your answer were downvoted lol

Comment: In your two sets of code, you're running a different test. In the first, you're only checking the default schema of the current user. If you were also checking what user you were executing as, I think you'd see that you're running as `username`. Whereas in the second code block, you're running as `dbo`.

Comment: Ya, I can't remember why I resorted to 'execute as' - I think what I'm looking for is a post that documents all the things that *prevent* you from successfully using the default schema - being a member of sysadmin is one, being a member of db_owner is another (I think) - but how many different caveats are there?